# Is patch SUPEE-6788 for Magento EE 1.9 complete?

Tags: php, security, magento, patch

After applying the official patch [SUPEE-6788](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788) for Magento EE 1.9 (`PATCH_SUPEE-6788_EE_1.9.1.1_v1-2015-10-30-07-07-46.sh`) I can see that 5 core modules are still using the old admin routing syntax (APPSEC-1034) :

- Mage_GoogleOptimizer
- Mage_GoogleBase
- Mage_Bundle
- Mage_Compiler
- Mage_Downloadable

There's also wrong calls left to `addFieldToFilter()` in file `app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Mysql4/Option/Collection.php` (use of backquotes is forbidden; APPSEC-1063).

All previous security patches have been applied (I also tested it on a Magento EE 1.9.1.1 vanilla with the same results).

Does anyone know if I should worry for the security of this platform?

Comment: Did you contact EE support? As EE 1.9 is pretty old, you should ask them for assistance.

Comment: Not yet but it was my next action. They're just usually not really fast at replying...

Comment: Just for info, after contacting the support, Magento is currently working on a new version of the patch for EE 1.9 and CE 1.4. It should be released soon.